# c++ templates and ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, overloading

I'm stuck with the following problem. I was using Xcode 7 and had no issue with my project. After trying to compile it on Visual Studio Express 2015, I get the message `"Error  C2668  ambiguous call to overloaded function"` in the code. I couldn't find anything specific to visual studio related to the problem.

I made a minimal working example supposed to be used on VS (there's no error on Xcode). The weird part involves the `func2` part. It's as if VS compiler couldn't auto deduce more types and/or arguments than a limit.

**Update :**

A workaround was proposed by Sam Varshavchik consisting in using partial specialization with an intermediate template class. This is a solution that I would like to avoid. First because it's not convenient in the context it would apply in my code, second because this compilation error is unclear to me. This error doesn't show up in Xcode7, and func2 has no error even in VS. Despite the explanation of WhiZTiM to which I agree with, fact is, overloading in this context can sometimes work, and sometimes not. And I'd really like to know why.

**Update 2 :**

According to bogdan, this is probably a bug in GCC and MSVC. I'm going to try to report it. (I love so much this first week with visual studio)

**Update 3 :**

Bug reported at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3076577

### functions.h :

```
template <class T>
class BX {
public :
    BX() {}
    ~BX() {}
};

template <class T1, class T2>
class G {
public :
    G() {}
    ~G() {}
};

template <template <class T> class T1, class T>
class DT {};

class B {
public :
    //I want func to work
    template <template <class T> class T1, class T, class M>
    static void func(const M& m, const DT<T1, T>* dt, T1<T>& val) {}

    template <template <class T> class T1, class T, class M>
    static void func(const G<T1<T>, M>& g, const DT<T1, T>* dt, T1<T>& val) {}

    //here is a small variation of func as a test
    template <template <class T> class T1, class T, class M>
    static void func2(const M& m, const DT<T1, T>* dt) {}

    template <template <class T> class T1, class T, class M>
    static void func2(const G<T1<T>, M>& g, const DT<T1, T>* dt) {}
};
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {
    BX< int > bx;
    G<BX< int >, int> g;
    DT<BX, int>* dt;
    B::func(g, dt, bx);//Error  C2668   'B::func': ambiguous call to overloaded function
    B::func2(g, dt);//no error
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code examples with invalid `void main`. It misleads newbies and makes it necessary to edit the code before trying it. FTFY.

Comment: This looks like an MSVC (and GCC) bug. The second template overload is more specialized than the first according to the rules for partial ordering of function templates. That's why the second overload is correctly chosen for `func2`. Overload resolution should work the same for `func`. The example should be further reduced and reported as a bug.

Comment: @bogdan, did you test it ? I'm quite concerned the whole behaviour would only appears on my system. Also, reducing the example is tricky, I actually already did for the MWE. The actual equivalent of func in my code is more complicated than the func provided in this topic. I reduced it until I find another 'sistership' func2 compiling fine. In short : reducing func makes it compile.

Comment: Yes, it is fully reproducible on MSVC 2015 Update 3. By reducing it I meant something like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mtfWJXEtQ8lEP8ub).

Comment: Alright, thanks for the other MWE. I tried reporting it to microsoft but I am apparently not allowed to report bugs.. Do you think I should do it directly to gcc using https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ ? I've never done that before. I was also wondering, if I wish this bug to be fixed asap, which way should be the fastest, gcc or microsoft ? But maybe this kind of things takes years before being fixed

Comment: To report a bug on [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) you need an MS account but otherwise it should work. For GCC, you need a bugzilla account. I have both, so I can file the reports if you want. It's difficult to say how long it will take for them to be fixed - C++ compiler teams have a lot on their plate these days. From my experience with MSVC, some bugs were fixed quite quickly (a month or so before the fix was announced, and then a new release has to come out), a few others are still open after a couple of years.

Comment: Ok done on MS Connect. I had to check my profile for enabling bug submission.

Comment: Also did for bugzilla. I wanted to do it by myself like a grown up.. Thanks for proposing anyway. And, bogdan feel free to add an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @brahmin Good stuff, I've added the two reports to my watchlists (and upvoted on Connect); we'll see how it goes. I've added an answer with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: It looks like the bug was fixed for MSVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in MSVC and GCC. The call should resolve to the second overload (Clang and EDG are doing that).

For the call `B::func(g, dt, bx)`, name lookup finds the two `func` templates. Template argument deduction and substitution is performed on each of them in order to generate function template specialization declarations that can subsequently participate in overload resolution. Deduction succeeds for both templates and we're left with two specializations:

```
void B::func<BX, int, G<BX<int>, int>>(const G<BX<int>, int>&, const DT<BX, int>*, BX<int>&);
void B::func<BX, int, int>            (const G<BX<int>, int>&, const DT<BX, int>*, BX<int>&);
```

The two functions have identical parameter declaration clauses, so clearly overload resolution cannot distinguish between them based on conversions from the arguments of the call; it has to resort to the last two steps in the process.

First, if one of the functions is a template specialization and the other one is not, the non-template one is preferred; not applicable here.

Last, it looks at the templates from which the two specialization declarations were synthesized; if one of the templates is more specialized than the other according to the partial ordering of function templates, then the corresponding specialization is preferred. (This is the only place in the process where the original templates come back into play.)

The description below is not very accurate and skips quite a few details, but I'm trying to concentrate on the parts that are relevant to this case. Very roughly:

- First, references and cv-qualifiers are stripped from the function parameter declarations of both templates, yielding:

  ```
  F1(M          , const DT<T1, T>*, T1<T>)
  F2(G<T2<U>, V>, const DT<T2, U>*, T2<U>)
  ```

  (template parameter names changed to avoid confusion)
- Then, deduction is attempted as if for a call to one template using the forms of the function parameters of the other template as arguments, and then the other way around. In this case, the last two pairs of corresponding parameters have identical forms, so deduction succeeds both ways. For the first pair of corresponding parameters:

  - Deducing `M` from an argument of the form `G<T2<U>, V>` works; `M` is deduced as `G<T2<U>, V>`.
  - Deducing `T2`, `U` and `V` in `G<T2<U>, V>` from an argument of the form `M` doesn't work (`M` can be anything).

  In other words, `G<T2<U>, V>` is a "more specific" form than `M`; it cannot represent all the types that `M` can represent; this is the intuitive meaning that *more specialized* is trying to formalize in this context.
- So, deduction works for all pairs of corresponding parameters from `F2` to `F1`, but not the other way around. This makes `F2` more specialized than `F1` in terms of partial ordering.

This means that the specialization corresponding to the second template is preferred in overload resolution.

Answer (score 3):

You made this call:

```
B::func(g, dt, bx);
```

Where:

- `g` is of type `G<BX< int >, int>`
- `dt` is of type `DT<BX, int>*`
- `bx` is of type `BX< int >`

Now you have these two functions:

```
template <template <class T> class T1, class T, class M>
static void func(const M& m, const DT<T1, T>* dt, T1<T>& val) {}
               //^^^^^^^^^^

template <template <class T> class T1, class T, class M>
static void func(const G<T1<T>, M>& g, const DT<T1, T>* dt, T1<T>& val) {}
               //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

During overload resolution; and considering only the first parameters in your function declarations (since those are what supposedly makes the function declarations different):

- `M` in the first function overload gets deduced as `G<BX< int >, int>`.
- The second function overload has a templated type that should be matched.

  - `T` can be deduced from `bx` as an `int`
  - `T1<T>` a template template type and is deduced from `bx` as `BX< int >`
  - `M` will match anything.
  - At the end of the day, you have that first parameter deduced as `G<BX< int >, int>` which is same as that of the first function

[GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa677983951f37ff) also raises an ambiguity error.

---

To give preference to the second overloaded function whenever a type of `G<...>` is passed, you'll need to use partial specializations. (Since they are ranked higher than primary templates). Please see 
[Sam Varshavchik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39060304/1621391) for one possible way of doing this.

Comment: This analysis is correct. What's missing from this answer, however, is a solution.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, Haha. I was still editing my *answer*. Nonetheless, I've applied "Division of Labor" here. I have made a brief summary of a possible solution and have referenced your *answer* for implementation. :-).

Comment: I agree with the diagnosis indeed. But why func2 doesn't raise any ambiguity then ?

Comment: And also, why is it compiling fine on Xcode7, and providing the expected behviour at runtime ?

Answer (score 2):

The apparent intent of the shown code is a partial function specialization.

Which ...is not going to work.

So, what to do, what to do... Well, how about transmogrifying a partial function specialization into an ordinary template class specialization?

My solution specializes a template on the first function parameter type in order to disambiguate the static class, and forward it to one of two ultimate class methods.

A good C++ compiler should be able to optimize away the extra function call layer:

```
template <class T>
class BX {
public :
    BX() {}
    ~BX() {}
};

template <class Tdata, class Tmetric>
class G {
public :
    G() {}
    ~G() {}
};

template <template <class T> class T1, class T>
class DT {};

template<class M> class B_func;

class B {
public :
    template <template <class T> class T1, class T, class M>
    static void func(const M& m, const DT<T1, T>* dt, T1<T>& val)
    {
        B_func<M>::func(m, dt, val);
    }

    template <template <class T> class T1, class T, class M>
    static void func_a(const M& m, const DT<T1, T>* dt, T1<T>& val) {}

    template <template <class T> class T1, class T, class M>
    static void func_b(const G<T1<T>, M>& g, const DT<T1, T>* dt, T1<T>& val) {}

    //here is a small variation of func as a test
    template <template <class T> class T1, class T, class M>
    static void func2(const M& m, const DT<T1, T>* dt) {}

    template <template <class T> class T1, class T, class M>
    static void func2(const G<T1<T>, M>& g, const DT<T1, T>* dt) {}
};


template <class M>
class B_func {
public:
    template<class two, class three>
    static void func(const M& m, const two* dt, three& val)
    {
        B::func_a(m, dt, val);
    }
};

template <template <class T> class T1, class T, class M>
class B_func<G<T1<T>, M>> {
public:
    template<class two, class three>
    static void func(const G<T1<T>, M>& m, const two* dt, three& val)
    {
        B::func_b(m, dt, val);
    }
};


int main() {
    BX< int > bx;
    G<BX< int >, int> g;
    DT<BX, int>* dt;
    B::func(g, dt, bx);
    B::func2(g, dt);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, adding a struct/class specialization layer is indeed a solution. I didn't test it yet but I'm pretty sure it's working as expected since I also use it in other part in the code. But I'd like to completely understand why XCode7 and VS2015 have different interpretations at compilation time. And why func2 doesn't raise this ambiguity as it then should be if func raises one.

Comment: Also, to be specific, I'm not trying to partially specialize a template function, but overloading it.